# Websocket handshake error (400) on AWS and Jupyter Notebook EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So, on an EC2 instance i have an application running which is not accessible on my network but available when i connect via my phone or an external network. The Chrome developer console gives me `Websocket connection to <public DNS> failed:Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400`.

Some threads here on SO suggest creating load balancers, I tried using the TCP on port 80 but the issue still persists.

I'm not sure what I can do to allow access, I cannot change the code as the EC2 instance is created from a template ([Open Data Cube-AWS](https://github.com/opendatacube/cube-in-a-box)).

Any suggestion would be helpful,
Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Sorry @That1Guy It's been so long I don't even remember this anymore.